Does light change phase when reflected from different thicknesses of glass coated one side with a silver reflector?

Will the reflected waves have different phase angles based on the ratio of the two thicknesses $t_1$ and $t_2$?

Upon reflection waves change phase by $\pi$,- they invert propagation direction.
Let's denote thickness difference of these layers with $\Delta L=t_2-t_1$. If you will emit waves with the same phase at the same time to these surfaces, then phase difference of them after reflection right near the interface of these layers will be :
$$ \Delta \phi  = \pi~\frac {\Delta L - n\lambda}{\lambda} \tag 1$$
where $n=0,1,2,3\ldots$,- is whole number of wavelengths which fit completely in $\Delta L$ distance.
This principle is exploited in, for example, anti-reflective coatings (in various optical elements), so that one reflected wave maximum would meet from other surface reflected wave minimum and so cancel each other in destructive interference.

Thank you. So if I make t1 = 1λ and t2 =2λ the phase difference will be π?

No. In your example $\Delta L = 2\lambda-1\lambda =\lambda$ and $n=1$ (exactly one whole wavelength fits the gap $t_2-t_1$), then by substituting this data into (1) you will see that the answer is zero radians,- i.e. no phase difference at all between reflected waves.

Thank you for your patience and clear answers. Perhaps my question has been too vague. I was trying to see if its possible to get a phase shift of π or a more general case of nπ/m where n and m are integers.

If you want a phase shift of $\pi$ then use a quarter wavelength condition of interference coating, i.e. $\Delta L = n\lambda /4$, but single layer $n=1$ works best as other options adds dependence on incident angle, etc. BTW, probably I have made an error in (1) formula as it is not tuned for getting maximum phase shift for $\lambda/4$ waveplate, but general idea is the same,- you count how much optical path length is similar or dis-similar to some required value and this will be your resulting phase shift.

Thank you for the information, its been very helpfull.
